# Homebrew - Trouble linking node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to get Node.js all set up and I'm a little lost because the commands I'm using wont work

Terminal reads:

```
   brew link node
 Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.35_1... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/dtrace/node.d
Target /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
brew link --overwrite node

 To list all files that would be deleted:
 brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

I have done 'brew link --overwrite node' but it still gives me the same result. I even look at an older kind of similar question and it didnt work either.

Comment: Does `brew link --overwrite node` emit any additional messages? Have you tried removing the conflicting file?

Comment: when I try to link run " brew link node' it get Error: Could not symlink lib/dtrace/node.d
Target /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d'